# Is there a difference in how texture coordinates work in OpenGL ES 1.x and later versions?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am currently reading this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Android-Games-Mario-Zechner/dp/1430246774](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430246774)

The book covers OpenGL ES 1.0. In the chapter discussing texture mapping, it is said that the origin of the texture coordinates is in the upper-left corner of the image. However, the information I find on Google is different - everywhere I look it is explained that the origin is the bottom-left corner.

Can someone clarify which one is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an error in the book. The texture origin is the lower-left pixel always, on all OpenGL versions.

If the example code in the book works nonetheless the author of the book he as very likely uploaded his textures upside down. OpenGL Textures are uploaded from the bottom to the top and images are usually stored top to bottom within their files. If so two errors cancel each other out and everything looks okay again.